# Existence of a matrix whose power is $I$.

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Let $m,n \ge 2$ be integers. Does there exist a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that
   $$
   A^m=I \ne A^k \ \forall\ k \in\{1,\ldots, m-1\}?
   $$
   For $n=2,3,4$ and $m=3$ the answer is yes (see, e.g. [Is there any matrix $2\times 2$ such that $A\neq I$ but $ A^3=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58666/is-there-any-matrix-2-times-2-such-that-a-neq-i-but-a3-i?rq=1) and [Find a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$ where $A\neq I$ and $A^2 \neq I$, but $A^3 = I$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206394/find-a-4-times-4-matrix-a-where-a-neq-i-and-a2-neq-i-but-a3-i/206403#206403) and the various answers to those question)
2. Does there exist a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ which is not a rotation and such that
   $$
   A^3=I\ne A, A^2?
   $$

Comment: If by "not a rotation" you mean $\vert\det\vert\ne 1$ then no. Powers of the matrix give powers of the determinant, and thus no possibility of $I$ in the power unless $\vert \det \vert = 1$

Comment: I really meant a rotation, i.e. $a_{11}=a_{22}=\cos\theta, a_{12}=-a_{21}=-\sin\theta$ for some $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. For $|\lambda|\ne 0,1$, the matrix $\text{diag}(\lambda,\lambda^{-1})$ is not a rotation, although it has determinant 1.

Comment: I thought that you may be thinking about that, so consider then the individual eigenvalues. They follow the same pattern in the powers, $\lambda \rightarrow \lambda^2 \rightarrow \lambda^3 \ldots$ and still no possibility of $I$ which has all eigenvalues of $1$. Unless they all have magnitude of $1$. Which would mean it is a rotation.

Answer (score 2):

The $2 \times 2$ matrix representations of the complex $m$th roots of unity satisfy your definition, e.g.:
$$ z = e^{2\pi i/m}, \quad A = \left[ \begin{matrix} Re(z) & Im(z) \\ -Im(z) & Re(z) \end{matrix} \right] $$
Of course, you can trivially extend this to any size matrix by embedding it as a submatrix.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary $n \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ and $m = 2$, the rotation matrix works. For $m > 2$, just put a $2$-by-$2$ rotation matrix as a submatrix. (The answer is actually in the links you posted.)